# Menu auto-ajustavel com li's

Tags: html, css

Como eu posso criar um menu auto ajustável sem usar nenhuma tabela, somente li? Ou seja, criar um menu horizontal onde as li's se ajustassem na largura sem ultrapassar o tamanho da ul conforme fosse adicionando itens!

Este site aqui: apple.com/br tem uma barra de busca em cima que quando clicamos nele, os menus diminuem, eu queria fazer mais ou menos assim no meu site. obrigado!

Valeu!!

Comment: Definindo um `width` em uma `ul`, caso o número de `li` ultrapasse o valor definido a lista vai se quebrar em uma nova linha.

Comment: Este site aqui: apple.com/br tem uma barra de busca em cima que quando clicamos nele, os menus diminuem, eu queria fazer mais ou menos assim no meu site. obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

De uma maneira bem simples, seu problema se resolve com `li{display: inline}`. Dessa maneira, os `li` alinham-se horizontalmente, e quebram linha conforme necessário.

Comment: Este site aqui: http://www.apple.com/br/ tem uma barra de busca em cima que quando clicamos nele, os menus diminuem, eu queria fazer mais ou menos assim no meu site. obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma solução com [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
largMenu = 0; //Esta variável vai juntar a largura inicial de cada item do menu em um único valor

$('nav > ul > li').each(function(){
    largMenu += $(this).width(); //A largura de cada item é somado
});
$('nav > ul > li').each(function(){
    $(this).width((((100 * $(this).width()) / largMenu)) + '%'); //A largura de cada item é dada em porcentagem
});
```

Nesse modelo sugerido usaremos o `nav` do HTML5. vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2 maior</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1 ainda maior</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1 final</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

O css básico para esse modelo:

```
/*Reseta os elementos do menu*/
nav, nav >ul, nav > ul > li {display:block; position:relative; margin:0; padding:0; list style:none;}

nav > ul > li {float:left;}
```

Se por algum motivo o menu quebrar linha, basta remover uma pequena porcentagem da largura de cada item no seguinte trecho: `$(this).width((((100 * $(this).width()) / largMenu) - 0.9) + '%'); //A largura de cada item é dada em porcentagem`. O `- 0.9` é o ponto em questão.

Espero ter ajudado ;D.

Comment: Obs: Só com HTML e CSS, isso é impossível (até agora).